# Tooltips for mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tooltips for mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539006/tooltips-for-mobile-browsers)

Maybe this is more of a UX question than a CSS question. I currently set the `title` attribute of some HTML if I want to provide more information:

```
<p>An <span class="more_info" title="also called an underscore">underline</span> character is used here</p>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.more_info {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

Works very nice, visual indicator to move the mouse over and then a little popup with more information.  But on mobile browsers, I don't get that tooltip.  `title` attributes don't seem to have an effect.  What's the proper way to give more information on a piece of text in a mobile browser?  Same as above but use Javascript to listen for a click and then display a tooltip-looking dialog?